# Does Apple mandate authorization via SSL?

Tags: ios, https, app-store, authorization, security

A friend of mine claims that Apple rejects applications that use vanilla HTTP for authentication.
I am unable to verify this information and Google doesn't say anything on the topic.

Are there any known cases of an app being rejected on the grounds that it doesn't use SSL?

Comment: I don't know if they would reject on those grounds, but it seems fairly pointless to perform authorisation to a back end over an insecure connection. One thing I can say is that if you do want to connect to a SSL service, the certificate must be from a trusted vendor, self-generated certificates and those from dubious providers will fail connection without very helpful reasoning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple doesn't care about how you handle data transfer security. I am the author of an app which is available for over a year. The app got a couple of updates which all went through the approval process and the app never used HTTPS for sign up.

Even apps like Twitter or Facebook didn't use HTTPS in the first years of iOS.